# Calling function from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, function

I'm working on an app in Xcode and I'm currently trying to access a separate class and call a function there.

---

**Code for sending the message**

```
-(IBAction) reloadButton:(id)sender
{
    RootViewController *theInstance = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow" bundle:nil];
    [theInstance reloadTableView];
}
```

**Calling the method**

*.h File*

```
-(void) reloadTableView;
```

*.m File*

```
-(void)reloadTableView
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Whenever I build, there are no errors. But when I run the app and press the 'reloadButton', it crashes and says "Program received signal: SIGABRT" at the line:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

What could be the problem and how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: the c, c++ and c# tags prove, that you have no idea. The language you are using is Objective-C. maybe you should start at the beginning. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: hahaha ik what i'm doing. I just typed in c and those tags came up. Thank you though. Ill fix it

Comment: Objective-C starts with an «O»

Comment: thank you vikingosegundo

Comment: honestly: start at the beginning.

Comment: nothing to do with xcode either, its an IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your class actually used as a data source? Otherwise, call:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: It is. I believe the problem has to do something with the fact that I'm using "self" in the function. See, if I access it locally, it works fine, but when I try to access it from another class, it crashes.

Comment: Ok. Maybe the answer to the question in the link can help you then by using NSNotification:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148948/iphone-sdk-reload-tableview-data-from-a-separate-class

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the RootViewController did not initialize its tableView correctly. In the debugger, try accessing the value in self.tableView.

Comment: Well, I tried to call the same function within the RootViewController class and it worked perfectly. So basically, I added a reloadButton to RootViewController and called the function using [self reloadTableView].

Comment: The reloadButton method in your above code creates a new RootViewController, which perhaps is missing some initialization that is happening otherwise.

Comment: Does `-initWithNibName` call `-viewDidLoad`?  Because `-viewDidLoad` would be a common place to initialize things such as the `tableView'.

Answer (score 0):

The RootViewController object doesn't look like it's being used.

You're alloc - initing it in the method, but not doing anything with it - not adding it's view anywhere, not setting datasources or delegates.

And at the end of the method it's out of scope.